# How to change the text color with hover in css

Tags: css, button, hover, rollover, squarespace

I'm trying to create a hover where the button changes color while the text changes to a different color, specifically in Squarespace. I'd like the button to turn white and the text to turn black. The button changes, but the text will not change.

Here's my css:

```
li {
  width: 190px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

li {
  vertical-align: absolute;
  margin: 5px;
}

li:hover {
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  color: #000000;
}
```

[CSS Hover Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTglg.png)

Comment: `vertical-align: absolute` is incorrect. You could also merge the two `li` selectors into just one.

Comment: As you have specified that it is a button, I am presuming that there is an anchor tag inside each of the `li` tags. In that case, you must apply the CSS related to the text (like `color`) to the `a` tag and not the `li` tag.

Comment: The default color is already black, try a different color.

Comment: OP, please paste your HTML also.